# how to connect a device send a message then close the connection of BlueTooth in android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth, message, send

I have with an blue tooth application from android api sample.I am displaying blue tooth paired device in a list when the user selects a device try for send a message to selected paired device then that message should deliver to that device.From the a this specification i would like to develop as when user checks the paired device then type a message in edit field then click on send button.when user click on send button then the user can connect to selected device then send that message to that device then if delivery is success immediately close the connection.
   I have implemented code as follows

```
 ListView listDevicesFound;
 ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set up the window layout
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothChat.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
    listDevicesFound.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
    listDevicesFound.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listDevicesFound.setSelected(true);
    listDevicesFound.setClickable(true);
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
      if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
          for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
           String deviceBTName = device.getName();
           String deviceBTAddress = device.getAddress();
           btArrayAdapter.add(deviceBTName + "\n"  + deviceBTAddress);
          }
      }

      mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


          SparseBooleanArray checked = listDevicesFound.getCheckedItemPositions();
            Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            Log.v("prasad", "devices.size()===>>>"+devices.size());
            for (int j=0;j<=devices.size();j++) 
               {
                    System.out.println(j);
                    if(checked.get(j))
                    {
                        String devadd= listDevicesFound.getItemAtPosition(j).toString();
                        String devaddress=devadd.substring(0,devadd.length()-17);
                        Log.v("prasad", "address===>>>"+devaddress);


                        /*
                         *BluetoothDevice:
                         *Represents a remote Bluetooth device. 
                         *A BluetoothDevice lets you create a connection with the respective device 
                         *or query information about it, such as the name, address, class, 
                         *and bonding state 
                         */

                        for(BluetoothDevice itDevices:devices)
                        {
                            Log.v("prasad", "itDevices.getAddress()===>>>"+itDevices.getAddress());
                            if(devadd.endsWith(itDevices.getAddress()))
                            {



                                            Log.v("1111","Here the adderess of selected device :"+itDevices.getAddress());


             }
         }
      }
   }




         //Please help on following steps
         //1.How to connect to a selected device code here                

         String message = messageEdit.getText().toString();
         //2.How to send the message to selected device here

         //3.How to close the connection with selected device here



            }
    });


  }
```

please follow my comments in coding lines

please any body help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Bluetooth Chat sample app?  I think that is very close to what you are trying to do:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Also, the Android Bluetooth Developer's Guide has code samples related to the specific questions you asked:

//1.How to connect to a selected device code here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices
Tells you how to call accept() on a BluetoothServerSocket to listen for incoming on one side, and then call connect() on a BluetoothSocket on the other side.

//2.How to send the message to selected device here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection
Explains about attaching your socket to I/O streams and then calling read/write on the streams.

//3.How to close the connection with selected device here
You just call close() on your BluetoothSockets.  Typically you do this from one thread, which causes the pending operation in your Bluetooth thread to throw an I/O Exception.

But again, I would recommend reading through the Chat sample and the Developer Guide, as listed above.